# Django 3 TypeError: context must be a dict rather than set

Tags: python, django

Please am new to programming and am building a website with django 3.0.2 with a tutorial of django 1.10 but i ran into error , i have searched for possible solutions but couldn't get one

here is the output from the terminal

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\TGPB\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\TGPB\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\TGPB\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\TGPB\blog\views.py", line 12, in post_list
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts: posts'})
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\TGPB\env\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\TGPB\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\TGPB\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 59, in render
    context = make_context(context, request, autoescape=self.backend.engine.autoescape)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\TGPB\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\context.py", line 270, in make_context
    raise TypeError('context must be a dict rather than %s.' % context.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: context must be a dict rather than set.
```

Here is my view

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Author, Tag, Category, Post


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Django")

#View function to display list of posts
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts: posts'})
```

and my post_list template

```
{% extends "blog/base.html"  %}

{% block title %}
    Blogg - {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}    

    <div class="content">
        <div class="section-inner clearfix">        

        {% for post in posts %}
            <h3>                        
                <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{ post.pk }}/">{{ post.title|capfirst }}</a>
            </h3>
            <p class="post-info">
                <span>Date: {{ post.pub_date }} </span> |
                <span>Category: <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/{{ post.category.slug }}">{{ post.category.name }}</a></span> |
                <span>Tag:
                {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                      <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/tag/{{ tag.slug }}">{{ tag.name }}</a>
                {% empty %}
                      None
                {% endfor %}
                </span> 
            </p>
        {% empty %}
            <p>There are no posts</p>
        {% endfor %}    

        </div>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your view you have a bug

posts should be the variable not a string

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Author, Tag, Category, Post


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello Django")

#View function to display list of posts
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i was bothered , never knew it could be from there

Answer (score 0):

In your function  ***post_list*** in ***views.py*** file  `{'posts: posts'}` should be `{'posts':posts}` *posts should be a variable not a string* change that and it will work fine.

```
def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})
```